# how send string array using tcp in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sockets, tcp

I want to send a string array from server to client using TCP/IP. I tried this code but it says "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable"

```
string[] strarray = new [] { "0", "1", "2", "3"};
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
var myString = serializer.Serialize(strarray);
// Send your string over the wire
m_writer.WriteLine(myString);
m_writer.Flush();
```

i know the code is incorrect but if you know any other way to send string array using tcp/ip please let me know

Comment: `serializer.Serialize(strarray)` is incorrect. All the `Serialize` methods returns void. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] strarray = new [] { "0", "1", "2", "3"};
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
string myString;

using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(xw, strarray);
        myString = sw.ToString();
    }
}
```